# How to sample from different values in a column but only return records that are unique from another column?

Tags: sql, teradata

I am struggling with a sampling issue using Teradata

Below is the format of the data

```
ID    Group     Rank
1     dog       1 
1     cat       1 
1     lion      1  
1     elephant  2 
2     dog       1 
2     cat       1 
2     lion      1 
2     elephant  1 
3     dog       1
3     cat       2 
3     lion      1 
3     elephant  1 
4     dog       2 
4     cat       1 
4     lion      1 
4     elephant  1 
...
```

I would ideally like to return a sample number for each entry in Group but with only unique values from ID.

Below is the current query I produced but this returns duplicates for ID

```
SELECT ID, Group FROM Table 
WHERE rank = 1 
SAMPLE 
 WHEN group = 'dog' then 10
 WHEN group = 'cat' then 10
 WHEN group = 'elephant' then 5
 WHEN group = 'lion' then 5
END
```

Comment: a bit of clearification would be helpful. What is `column A` and `column B`? Maybe replace these names with the actual names of your columns in your table. Also the result you provided looks very suspectly like a so called _cartesian product_. So your `SAMPLE` clause always evaluates `true`. This is often based on a misformulated condition

Comment: Remove duplicates before sampling?

Comment: @CiaranSheelan . . . Solving this problem requires recursive CTEs.  It could be quite expensive if you have a large amount of data.

Comment: @GordonLinoff the data would be pretty large with over ~1m rows would it be better to look at using for loops using Python?

Comment: @CiaranSheelan . . . I'm not sure.  Do you have to return all ids?  What if that is not possible?  The question needs more information.

Comment: @GordonLinoff no I do not need to return all ids I am just sampling from the full population. Similar to the example query I need to sample x number of records from each value in Group

Comment: What's the number of IDs & groups?

Comment: @dnoeth there are 31 distinct groups and 358,720 distinct IDs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with cte as
 (
   SELECT ID, Group,
      random(1,10000) as rnd -- RANDOM can't be directly used in OLAP-functions
   FROM Table 
   WHERE rank = 1 
 )
SELECT ID, Group
FROM cte
QUALIFY 
   ROW_NUMBER() -- get one random row per ID
   OVER (PARTITION BY ID 
         ORDER BY rnd) = 1
SAMPLE 
 WHEN group = 'dog' then 10
 WHEN group = 'cat' then 10
 WHEN group = 'elephant' then 5
 WHEN group = 'lion' then 5
END
```

Comment: thanks this worked just a typo PARITTION -> PARTITION

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have enough records, choose a random row for each id and then choose the appropriate numbers from that:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by group order by seqnum) as sequm_g
      from (select t.*,
                   row_number() over (partition by id order by random(1, 1000000))
            from t
           ) t
      where seqnum = 1
     ) t
where (group in ('dog', 'cat') and seqnum_g <= 10) or
      (group in ('elephant', 'lion') and seqnum_g <= 5) ;
```

This doesn't guarantee that the groups will be big enough in the result set.  But if you have enough data relative to the size of the groups, then it should work.

Comment: getting an error on this; RANDOM function can not be used in Aggregates or Ordered Analytical Functions